# See which files are installed when installing a package with tlmgr

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

Is there a log somewhere that tells me what files where installed when I install a package with `tlmgr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call

```
tlmgr info imakeidx --list
```

where after `info` you put a package you have installed, you get

```
package:     imakeidx
category:    Package
shortdesc:   A package for producing multiple indexes.
longdesc:    The package enables the user to produce and typeset one or more indexes simultaneously with a document. The package is known to work in LaTeX documents processed with pdflatex, xelatatex and lualatex. If makeindex is used for processing the index entries, no particular setting up is needed when TeX Live is used. Using xindy or other programs it is necessary to enable shell escape; shell escape is also needed if splitindex is used.
installed:   Yes
revision:    31166
sizes:       src: 69k, doc: 501k, run: 17k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.3a
cat-date:    2013-07-11 13:45:25 +0200
cat-license: lppl1.3
collection:  collection-latexextra
Included files, by type:
run files:
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.sty
source files:
  texmf-dist/source/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.dtx
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/imakeidx/README details="Readme"
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf details="Package documentation"
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/imakeidx/manifest.txt
```